# how to set up auto-discovery for a container?

Tags: datadog

I have configured the docker-daemon,and also added modified the auto_conf. How should i pass the  %%host%%  variable?

```
sudo docker run -d --name dd-agent \
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro \
  -v /proc/:/host/proc/:ro \
  -v /sys/fs/cgroup/:/host/sys/fs/cgroup:ro \
  -e API_KEY=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \
  -e SD_BACKEND=docker \
  -e SD_CONFIG_BACKEND=etcd \
  -e SD_BACKEND_HOST=XX.XXX.XX.XX \
  -e SD_BACKEND_PORT=XXXX \
  datadog/docker-dd-agent:latest
```

changed the etcd.yaml

```
docker_images:
  - image1

init_config:

instances:
  - url: "http://XX.XXX.XX.XX:XXXX"
```

but when i try to do

sudo docker exec -it dd-agent /etc/init.d/datadog-agent configcheck

```
2017-08-07 19:18:37,637 | WARNING | dd.collector | utils.service_discovery.abstract_sd_backend(abstract_sd_backend.py:66) | Failed to interpolate variable %%host%% for the url parameter. Dropping this configuration.
```

the collector logs show

```
NotFound: 404 Client Error: Not Found ("No such image: sha256:6d13e6f1665c7abcd9edeba651a1f883ab68dbb73153d6cc55145add585373fc")
2017-08-08 17:16:11 UTC | ERROR | dd.collector | utils.dockerutil(dockerutil.py:548) | Exception getting docker image name
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/datadog-agent/agent/utils/dockerutil.py", line 533, in image_name_extractor
    image_spec = self.client.inspect_image(image)
  File "/opt/datadog-agent/embedded/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docker/utils/decorators.py", line 21, in wrapped
    return f(self, resource_id, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/datadog-agent/embedded/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docker/api/image.py", line 136, in inspect_image
    self._get(self._url("/images/{0}/json", image)), True
  File "/opt/datadog-agent/embedded/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docker/client.py", line 178, in _result
    self._raise_for_status(response)
  File "/opt/datadog-agent/embedded/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docker/client.py", line 173, in _raise_for_status
    raise errors.NotFound(e, response, explanation=explanation)
```

Answer (score 1):

hmm, so you're trying to use autodiscovery to find which container the dd-agent should be running the etcd check on? and you're using the auto_conf files approach? And there, you're wondering how to apply the `%%host%%` template variable?

If that's what you're interested in, I think you'll want to add it into your `etcd.yaml` on the `url` line, as shown in [the example file](https://github.com/DataDog/integrations-core/blob/5.15.x/etcd/auto_conf.yaml#L7) like so:

```
docker_images:
  - etcd

init_config:

instances:
  - url: "http://%%host%%:%%port_0%%"
```

Comment: no that did not work? i have a container A that is accessible in ipaddress :port , i am trying set up auto-discovery for that url. but i seem i can't make it work.
i modified the apache and etc file to point to the container image and then i gave the host and port in the docker dd-agent image.
is this how we setup auto-discovery?

Comment: hmm, i dunno. i think at this point you may want to reach out to the datadog support team (support@datadoghq.com) for more pointed guidance, they're very responsive, and are very good at troubleshooting this kind of thing.